# Working with the UI Table View, iOS 7

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, xcode5

I have `UI View Table` and `Simple View` controllers in my project. They are connected with each other by navigation controller. At the top of the `UI View Table`, there is a button "Add new location" that invokes segue to the `Simple View`. The latter has the text field that has to be filled by the user. When the user taps the "Back" button then he/she has to see the "updated" UI Table View with the newly added cell.

In order to pass data between these view, I am using singleton class (from my point of view, that perfectly fits the MVC paradigm). This object has `NSMutableArray` as the property that updates when user has finished typing the at the text field at the `Simple View` controller.

However, when I launch the application at the first time, press the Add new location button, enter the text at the text field and hit back - nothing happens i.e. the UI Table doesn't update.

But, when I repeat the same steps again, two (the same) cells are added to the UI Table View.

Could you please hint me how can I fix this issue i.e. add only one cell to the UI Table view when user presses Back button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because -(IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender is triggered twice. You've to put the method to add the data in your viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated, with a check for null values:

```
-(IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender{

}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    if ([_textSearch.text length] == 0) return;

    NSLog(@"%@", _textSearch.text);
    _info.isEdited=YES;
    _info=[GeoChatInformationAboutTheSelectedPlace returnInstance];
    [_info.arrayOfTheNamesOfTheLocations addObject:_textSearch.text];
    [_info.imagesOfTheSavedLocations addObject:@"car1.jpeg"];
    [_info.arrayOfTheNumberOfUpdatesOfTheSavedLocations addObject:@"1"];
    [_info.arrayOfTheOnLineUsersAtTheSavedLocations addObject:@"56"];
    [_info.arrayOfThePostsAssociatedWithTheSelectedLocation addObject:@3];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've to reload the UITableView data source in `viewWillAppear:animated` method of your tableview view controller:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _info=[GeoChatInformationAboutTheSelectedPlace returnInstance];
    //[self.tableView reloadData];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

ps: car1.jpeg and car2.jpeg are missing in your github project

Comment: Thank you for your advise. I did as you recommended but now, when I click at the second time "Add new location", the previously entered text added as the new cell again.

Comment: This is because -(IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender is triggered twice. You've to put the method to add the data in your viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated, with a check for null values: -(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    
    if ([_textSearch.text length] == 0) return;
    
    NSLog(@"%@", _textSearch.text); ecc ecc

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped me. Could you please insert your comment above in your answer to my question? I would like to accept your suggestion as the right solution to my issue.